# Enhanced Michigan driver's license for travel between Michigan and Ontario

Tags: driving, paperwork

How can I get my MI driver's license enhanced, or get an enhanced MI state ID?

Answer (score 6):

To [get an enhanced Michigan driver's license](http://www.michigan.gov/sos/0,1607,7-127-1627_8669_9040-213045--,00.html) if you already have one, you only need to visit [any Secretary of State branch office](http://services.sos.state.mi.us/servicelocator/branchofficelocator.aspx) and bring essentially the same documents you would need to apply for the driver's license originally, plus proof of U.S. citizenship, such as your birth certificate. (A [complete list of acceptable documents](http://www.michigan.gov/documents/sos/SOS-428_275188_7.pdf) is available.)

In particular, you need:

1. Your Social Security card.
2. Proof of citizenship.
3. Proof of identity (your current Michigan DL is sufficient).
4. Proof of residence (your current Michigan DL is sufficient).

If your DL is expired, you will need to bring additional documents for proof of identity and residence (see linked list above).

You'll have a new photo taken and receive your enhanced driver's license in two to three weeks.

Note that you'll have to turn in your old driver's license and be issued a temporary driver's license, but the temporary is not good for border crossing.